# Android TableLayout expressed as a percentage of LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to place a TableLayout as the only item inside a LinearLayout (It has a background icon I want to cover the whole screen) and I want to centre it and say use 60% of the width and 70% of the height for example. I have this, and it looks ok, but I am not sure it will work across many devices and am wondering whats the best, most general way to express it.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/mylogo"
    android:padding="0dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    >

    <TableLayout
        android:background="#FFFF0000"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:stretchColumns="field">

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I messed around with layout_Weights, but the only thing I managed to do was make the table disappear.

Thanks
Stephen

Answer (score 1):

`LinearLayout` can only do child sizing by weights for one dimension but as you're only worried really about sizing a single view, you can accomplish this by nesting `LinearLayout`s.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/mylogo"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="1.0">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1.0"
        android:layout_weight="0.7">

        <TableLayout
            android:background="#FFFF0000"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:stretchColumns="field"
            android:layout_weight="0.6">

        </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Whether this layout will look good across devices depends on your content. In general I tend towards reasonable paddings/margins, but again it's very dependent on content.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a RelativeLayout instead of the LinearLayout, because if there is only one child in the linear, it will occupy the full space of its parent.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the way you did is good. You'll probably have some differences between different devices, but you can set different layouts for other screens densities and orientations.

Using `layout_weight` would help only if you had more than one child inside the `LinearLayout`.

Comment: `layout_weight` works perfectly fine for a single child. You simply have to supply a `weightSum` on the LinearLayout.